# numpy strange results in solving an inequality

Tags: python, numpy

I have written an inequality by two formats the first shape is converting to a polynomial

the polynomial and the matrix multiplication are exactly the same

```
V0j=yj.T @ P @ yj=12137.5 * (y1**2) + 11438.7 * (y2**2) +(26.381 * 2)*y1*y2
```

and also I have the next the constant value

```
lambdaprimezero*nrmedoe0+minelement=8.920678
```

this means that polynomial inequality and the next inequality are the same and must have the same answer

```
yj.T @ P @ yj-lambdaprimezero*nrmedoe0<minelement
```

and with the help of a friend I could extract the points in which polynomial inequality is valid (first program)

The problem occurs when I use the answer of the firs program (polynomial inequality) in the matrix one

As the are the same the send program must return small enough at these points but it does not

```
#first part  
import numpy as np

# 12137.5x^2 + 11438.7y^2 + (26.381*2)xy = 0.000731

Y1 = np.linspace(-0.003, 0.003, num=100)
Y2 = np.linspace(-0.003, 0.003, num=100)

pointsInsideEllipse = []

for y1 in Y1:
    for y2 in Y2:
        if 12137.5 * (y1**2) + 11438.7 * (y2**2) +(26.381 * 2)*y1*y2 < 8.920678:
            pointsInsideEllipse.append([y1, y2])
#print(pointsInsideEllipse)
y=[y1, y2]
P=np.array([[12137.5, 26.381], [26.381,11438.7]])
yj=np.array(y)
pointset=np.array(pointsInsideEllipse)
def msquarefunc(yj):
    VALUE=yj.T @ P @ yj
    return VALUE
point=pointsInsideEllipse
for point in pointset:
     if msquarefunc(point)<8.920678:
      
############################################
###########################
       
# second program(matrix form)
       V0j=yj.T @ P @ yj
       testfeaturej=V0j-lambdaprimezero*nrmedoe0
#print(V0j)
#print(lambdaprimezero*nrmedoe0)
       cj=abs(testfeaturej)
print(cj)
if cj<=minelement:
   print('small enough')
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I wonder if you are seeing differences due to the imprecision  of floating-point values and calculations.  That's why floats are best compared with `np.isclose` or `np.allclose`.

Comment: Thnx. The difference is in the second program   when I choose the solutions from the solution set

it returns 8.70618639258 while it must return a number less than 0.0007313088105225123

Answer (score 1):

You used `y=[y1, y2]` while it should be `y=[Y1, Y2]`. Moreover, note that `point=pointsInsideEllipse` is useless since `point` is set by the following loop. The biggest issue comes from the fact that the first hypothesis is actually wrong. Indeed, `yj.T @ P @ yj` is not equal to `12137.5 * (y1**2) + 11438.7 * (y2**2) +(26.381 * 2)*y1*y2`. I do not see why it would be actually true. The y1 values multiplied seems not the same in one case while they are with the second.
Note that the rest of the code is not clear and incomplete and so hard to test/run.

You can use vectorized calls to make your code faster and more clear with Numpy. More over you can easily test that the equality hypothesis is wrong using the following code:

```py
Y1 = np.linspace(-0.003, 0.003, num=100)
Y2 = np.linspace(-0.003, 0.003, num=100)

yj = np.vstack([Y1, Y2])

V0j_1 = yj.T @ P @ yj
V0j_2 = 12137.5 * (Y1.reshape(-1,1)**2) + 11438.7 * (Y2**2) + (26.381*2)*np.outer(Y1,Y2)

# Another (less efficient) way of computing V0j_2:
#V0j_2_bis = np.array([[12137.5 * (y1**2) + 11438.7 * (y2**2) +(26.381 * 2)*y1*y2 for y2 in Y2] for y1 in Y1])
#print(np.allclose(V0j_2, V0j_2_bis)) # True

distance = (V0j_1 - V0j_2)**2
print(np.allclose(V0j_1, V0j_2)) # False
print(distance)

# This shows the two matrices have different symmetries (and so the assumption is wrong)
print(np.allclose(V0j_1, V0j_1.T)) # True
print(np.allclose(V0j_2, V0j_2.T)) # False
```

The `distance` matrix show huge difference (that are unrelated with floating-point errors). Actually some values of `V0j_1` and `V0j_2` are even note of the same sign.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. The reason why the two expressions must be equal comes from the next equality:

(y1,y2)^T*np.matrix([[a,b],[b,c]])*(y1,y2)=a*y1^2+2b*y1*y2+c*y2^2

I have used pythonic symbolism to show the matrix that is a mathematical expression.

I do not know if I can send link or images here.

Comment: For two values (y1,y2), it should be true indeed. But for two vector (Y1, Y2) like in your question, this should not be true anymore. Actually, one can see that the equality is fine for the first value by checking `np.isclose(V0j_1[0,0], V0j_2[0,0])` which is `True`.

Comment: Yes u r right but the vector is 2*1 on a set of values. (time varying in instances)